Application of frame differences over time in Computer Vision
Given incoming grayscaled image over time where the pixel intensity normalized from 0 until 1, let $c$ is current frame and $p$ is past frames. Let $diff$ is defined following:

$ diff_0 = |c-p|=|p-c| $
$ diff_1 = ReLU(c-p) $
$ diff_2 = ReLU(p-c) $

What are the common applications based on those three pixel difference functions?
What can I do with those three difference functions?
As far as I know, absolute subtraction is commonly used in anomaly detection.
How about ReLU? I feel there's something useful usage because the two frames distinguished based on time step.
